# Horizontal flyout menu using display:inline

Tags: css, menu

is it possible to create a horizontal flyout menu without using `float`?
I tried it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmHNa/) with `display:inline`.
My aim was to have a result like the second example.
Unfortunately I had to work with float ...

Do you have any idea what I am missing?
If you have a link, etc. post it, please.

Your help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
This is how far I got...
http://jsfiddle.net/gbMsq/2/

The second list-item should have another list under it. But it is set under the first list-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

#### Working Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/fjAUM/)

`example 3` uses `display: inline-block` instead of `float`, and vertically aligns the blocks to the top

#### Updated

fiddle updated to show the first example and the latest one in the OP.. both use the same CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try using absolute positioning like this:

```
li > ul { position: absolute; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/QmHNa/2/)

The downside/advantage is that the inner `ul` is taken out of flow, as seen in my demo. It might be good if you want a dropdown menu, if not, you can add some height to the outer `ul`, or stick to floats.